# website SEO advice needed

Tags: seo, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I have a website and it's been 4 days since I have provided sitemap file to Google. None of URLs are shown in Google. Google Webmaster Tools shows 4 URLs indexed. My website is session protected is this creating a problem?

Answer (score 1):

If Webmaster Tools / Search Console is not showing any crawling issues, then you just need to wait. Most sites will take longer than 4 days to be indexed.

Sitemaps are not necessary for a site to be crawled, but yours looks fine.

(I can actually see 6 pages in a search for `site:http://twekr.com/`.  If they are not high up in the listings for the terms you are after, that is a different issue.)

RE tools - Webmaster Tools / Search Console should flag up most issues - use "fetch as google" if you think they may not be able to see a page.